# How to prepare custom Alpine Linux ISO for unattended installation

Tags: kickstart, iso, alpine, syslinux

I am evaluating Alpine Linux to replace CentOS, Currently we prepare Custom ISO with kickstart for unattended installations. In my case from unattended I mean that deployer just put USB and after that installer finish without asking any input.

For Alpine i found link(https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/How_to_make_a_custom_ISO_image_with_mkimage) but need more details for following

- We can prepare answer file which mean still we have to run setup-alpine -f from prompt, Can we add answer file in ISO and instruct to run this as first command? Following i am using for centos in isolinux.cfg, Where MYISO is label of USB

`

```
  menu label ^Deploy Custom Node
  kernel vmlinuz
  append initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=MYISO inst.ks=hd:LABEL=MYISO:/ks/ks1.cfg quiet`
```

- In CentOS we can add picture as menu background, Can we do same in for Alpine?